# D-link DWR 710 not working

Tags: wireless-router

DWR 710 router is not working at all. Its switching on but I m unable to detect any wi-fi signal. I m also unable to connect it to my PC via USB. it shows 'device driver software was not successfully installed' and then it got disconnected.

please help

Thanx in advance

Comment: Um, did you install the device drivers?

Comment: it doesn't require any drivers.. Morever earlier it used to work just fine.

Comment: Your operating system disagrees :-)

Comment: it's also a plug and play device. after plugging it in the socket it used to work. but suddenly yesterday it stopped working. after plugging in it is  switching on (green led lights) but after that nothing happens.